# How to solve raised exception related to Updater happening with latest VS Code update only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-telegram-bot

I'm using Python Telegram Bot and Visual Studio Code. When I start my bot, after some seconds it raises an error that opens this message:

```
Could not load source '<string>': Source unavailable.
```

And the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\sergi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\telegram\\vendor\\ptb_urllib3\\urllib3\\connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
File "C:\\Users\\sergi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\http\\client.py", line 1198, in getresponse
response.begin()
File "C:\\Users\\sergi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\http\\client.py", line 297, in begin\n    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "C:\\Users\\sergi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\http\\client.py", line 258, in _read_status\n    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
File "C:\\Users\\sergi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\socket.py", line 576, in readinto\n    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
File "C:\\Users\\sergi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\ssl.py", line 937, in recv_into
return self.read(nbytes, buffer)\n  File "C:\\Users\\sergi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\ssl.py", line 799, in read
return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)\n  File "C:\\Users\\sergi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\ssl.py", line 583, in read
v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)\nsocket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "c:\\Users\\sergi\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2019.3.6558\\pythonFiles\\lib\\python\\ptvsd\\_vendored\\pydevd\\_pydevd_bundle\\pydevd_resolver.py", line 213, in _get_py_dictionary
attr = getattr(var, name)
AttributeError: characters_written
```

This wasn't happening on previous VS Code versions, only happens with the last update. Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: I have tested it on previous Visual Studio Code versions and the issue doesn't appear. So it's something related with the last update of VS Code. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by adding some arguments to Updater.

```
updater = Updater(token, request_kwargs={'read_timeout': 15, 'connect_timeout': 15})
```

You can try with other timeouts values. If you are still getting the error, try higher values.